# How to encode in base 64 and hex?

Tags: url, base64, hex

I read following two lines in the book : The Web Application Hacker’s Hand-
book.

For example, the Base64-encoded form of The Web Application Hacker’s Hand-
book is:
VGhlIFdlYiBBcHBsaWNhdGlvbiBIYWNrZXIncyBIYW5kYm9vaw==

For example, hex-encoding the username “daf” within a cookie would result in:
646166

Can anybody explain me how this conversion is done?

Comment: This helps quite a lot: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Thanks, got the first one. Now anything about the second one??

Comment: I got the second one to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about Base64 in the Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Doing the actual conversion to Base64 will depend on what programming language you are using. For instance, in the `System.Text` namespace of the .NET Framework you will find a method called `Convert.ToBase64String` that will do it for you.

For the hex encoding, all you need to do is get the corresponding hexadecimal value of each character. Take a look at this [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), in the `Hx` column you will see that `d` is `64`, `a` is `61` and `f` is `66`.

Again, the actual conversion will depend on the language you're using.